# How do I install Diablo 2 on Windows 7

Tags: diablo-ii, windows-7

Trying to download Diablo 2 on Windows 7. The disc says it’s compatible for it but it says it can’t find installer.

Can anyone give help with this?

Comment: Which disk are you trying to use?  I recall there being a play disk, and install disks.

Comment: where do you try to download it ?

Comment: I've found registering the key in Battle.net and then downloading their installer to be a lot less hassle than the disks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are looking at the install disc. If for some reason mounting the disc is not causing the Windows autorun system to automatically run the installer, you can do the following:

- At the root of the disc will be a text file called `autorun.inf`. This tells older versions of Windows what to run automatically when the disc is inserted. Open the file in a text editor.
- It should contain a line under the `[autorun]` heading that looks like `open=setup.exe` (where `setup.exe` may be some other executable, probably a launcher executable in Diablo 2's case). This is the executable that Windows would normally launch for you.
- Navigate to that `.exe` on the disc and double-click it. This should cause the launcher to open and let you install the game.

You could also dig around on the disc until you find a `setup.exe`, since that's what the actual installers are usually called. There may be more than one though, as the game may have included installers for dependency components (like modern games do with Direct3D runtimes, for example).

[More information than you probably want on the `autorun.inf` file can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf).

Comment: For information, the first installation disk contains both an "`INSTALL.EXE`" and a "`SETUP.EXE`" in the root directory. Running either of these will take you to the installation wizard. Alternatively, you can associate the Diablo II CD-Key with a Battle.net account, which gives you access to a downloadable installer.

Comment: That's good to know; I don't actually have discs for the game any longer so my answer is based mainly on the memory of them. And the way the autorun stuff works.

Comment: I just dug the disks out specifically to check. Feel free to include any of the above in your answer if you feel it would be an improvement (I've already upvoted it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Josh's answer is correct. The setup.exe is almost always located in the root directory of the disc, and it will be on the install disc. I had this to add, however:

Diablo II doesn't require registry information to play. Most games, when the installer is run, set registry values that primarily tell things where the game is located on your hard drive.
My suggestion to you is once the game is installed, save the entire install folder in a compressed archive somewhere so you don't have to bother again. Older games like Diablo II often have dated installers -- not to mention the 3 discs you have to switch between -- that take longer than it should to install your game.

Comment: It's still a good solution, but like I said it should be a last resort. I just don't really care about the morality of the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing even mentioning piracy in the answer means you've become an enemy of the state, so to speak?

Comment: Well, I personally think it's kind of unfair for the user to not know about this option available to them, but I guess I will remove it if it means my answer would become invalid.